# Sales>Orders grid columns "pending Sync"

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I have the **Magento ShipEasy and PickPack extension** installed.

Under `Sales>Orders` a few columns specifically **"Qty"** and a custom attribute **"Location"** are not showing data from orders but rather appearing as **"pending sync"** yet all other information on other columns appears.

Previously this error never appeared and all data would show up. It stopped working last week on thursday.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Amit